# Online data storage solution for large files

Tags: backup, data

I have two VeraCrypt containers totaling 5.3tb (3tb and 2.3tb) which I would like to copy to an external location (cloud storage, rented data center space or similar), in case of local loss of data. I don't need automatic backup but I need to be able to periodically overwrite the stored data (maybe monthly) and I need to be able to download the data in the event of data loss. I'm seeking to do this as cheaply as possible. I'm struggling to find a solution as many services seem to either cap data below this level, charge a lot for quantities of this kind, or struggle to upload this quantity of data in a reasonable time. What might be an appropriate online service?

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon Glacier? https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/

Comment: Why not purchase several NAS drives, house a NAS either at your house or family members and FTP the data there? Or better yet simply have a drive local and at families house and rotate the disks? When we're talking TBs OwnCloud and NAS just makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered by price:

- [Hubic](https://hubic.com/home/browser/) 10TB for €5/month, no transfer fees, bandwidth is about 6 MB/s
- [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) unlimited for $5/month, keeps historical files for 30 days
- Owning 6TB for about €200, excl. price for NAS
- [C14](https://www.online.net/en/c14) cheaper version of Amazon Glacier
- [Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/), branded backup, high retrieval fees
- [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) similar to Amazon S3
- [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) Infrequent access, branded data store

I am using Hubic and [zpaq](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) for deduplication so I don't transfer TBs every month. If performance become problem I would go with home NAS or even some cheap server housing.